# Using the debugger for UI and getting errors on config references

Tags: karate

I finally decided to take time out to setup the debugger detailed at: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/Debug-Server

Everything seems to be set up fine, however, my first attempts at debugging are yielding errors right off the bat.

There are exceptions being thrown at references to classpaths set in config files.

An example:

```
test_config.json file has:
{
 "functions": "classpath:general/etc/functions"
}

test.feature file has:
Feature: Test page
    Background:
        * call read(functions + 'secondary_method.feature')
```

When I run the debugger, there is exception being thrown on that first line under Background: "ReferenceError: "functions" is not defined.

This is just the first line in the file, I suspect there will be more issues. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I pass on this question

Comment: @PeterThomas  I created a stand-alone feature file (without any dependencies) and the debug worked well. I am assuming the UI debug sequence works well with current feature file opened and doesn't work when there are dependencies outside of the feature file being run (i.e calling other feature files from primary feature file).